# removing draft file after saving permanently in moodle File API

Tags: php, file-upload, moodle, file-manager

I'm using moodle `filemanager` to get a file from user and save it permanently like this:

```
$fs = get_file_storage();
$pluginname='profile_field_fileupload';
$pluginfolder= 'profile_field_profileimage';


$draftitemid=file_get_submitted_draft_itemid($this->inputname);
if (empty($entry->id)) {
    $entry = new stdClass;
    $entry->id = $this->userid;
}
$context = context_user::instance($this->userid);
$files = $fs->get_area_files($context->id, $pluginname,$pluginfolder,false,'',false);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $file->delete();
}

file_save_draft_area_files($draftitemid, $context->id, $pluginname,$pluginfolder,$entry->id,array('subdirs'=>false, 'maxfiles'=>1));
```

But draft still exists.
How should I remove draft after saving it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wait a few days - Moodle's cron process automatically cleans up draft files after that point (the delay is to make sure you haven't still got a copy of the form open and in use).

Remember that the draft area files are taking up no extra storage space on your server, as all files with identical content are stored only once, with multiple entries in the 'mdl_files' table all pointing to the same physical location on the server's hard disk.